# Why can't derived classes be substituted in place of base classes in interface members?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm unable to create an implementation of an interface that can work with a derived class. I have always thought this was possible, and I'm confused as to why I am unable to do this. It also is not possible if I change `BaseType` to an abstract class either.

```
public interface BaseType {}

public class FirstDerivedClass : BaseType {}

public class SecondDerivedClass : BaseType {}


public interface SomeInterface
{
    void Method(BaseType type);
}

public class Implementation : SomeInterface
{
    public void Method(FirstDerivedClass type) {}
}
```

`'Implementation' does not implement interface member 'SomeInterface.Method(BaseType)'`

Why is this not possible? I've come into a real world situation where this would be useful.

For example, Selenium WebDriver has a number of browser drivers. There is an abstract `DriverOptions` class with derived classes (`ChromeOptions`, `FirefoxOptions`, etc.).

This is an example of the real world problem I've got:

```
// Third party code - Selenium.
public abstract class DriverOptions {}
public class ChromeOptions : DriverOptions {}
public class FirefoxOptions : DriverOptions {}


// My code
public interface IWebDriverFactory
{
    IWebDriver GetWebDriver(DriverOptions options);
}

public class ChromeWebDriverFactory : IWebDriverFactory
{
    public IWebDriver GetWebDriver(ChromeOptions options)
    {
        // implementation details for initalising Chrome and use options from ChromeOptions
    }
}

public class FirefoxWebDriverFactory : IWebDriverFactory
{
    public IWebDriver GetWebDriver(FirefoxOptions options)
    {
        // implementation details for initalising Firefox and use options from FirefoxOptions
    }
}
```

Comment: [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), but you will need to use generics for it.

Comment: Do you have an example of that?

Comment: What about `SomeInterface a = new Implementation(); a.Method(new SecondDerivedBaseType());` ? How `Implementation` could handle this? It has only implementation for `FirstDerivedBaseType`.

Comment: Let's say I wanted a trolley (interface) that could take all types of food (IFood) in it. I present to you a HealthyTrolley (class) that takes **only** fruit. Does that meet the conditions? No - it can take **one** type of food but not **all** types of food. _The compiler is basically enforcing the same thing._

Comment: [Microsoft does...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I don't fully understand how I would go about applying those examples to this, unfortunately.

Comment: @user9993 Generics can't hack it really.

Comment: I'm not really experienced with Covariance and Contravariance myself, I just know it exists, so I'm not the right person to ask for an answer. If I did, I would probably post an answer and not just a comment...

Comment: Specifically the contract you got when you decided to implement the interface stipulates that **all** types are legal **as long as they implement BaseType**. Your method, which only takes one of the descendants, cannot take all those other types even though they might implement that interface. So this is not a technical limitation, what you're asking for isn't legal because it makes no sense.

Comment: In "the real world" you would probably be using an DI container that can register those factories and then you'd just resolve for that. I suggest using generics though. If that is your only use for that DI container, the you can write this code yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that using generic types and contravariance. Your code should look like below:

```
    // Third party code - Selenium.
public abstract class DriverOptions { }
public class ChromeOptions : DriverOptions { }
public class FirefoxOptions : DriverOptions { }


// My code
public interface IWebDriverFactory<in T> where T:DriverOptions
{
    IWebDriver GetWebDriver(T options);
}

public class ChromeWebDriverFactory : IWebDriverFactory<ChromeOptions>
{
    public IWebDriver GetWebDriver(ChromeOptions options)
    {
        // implementation details for initalising Chrome and use options from ChromeOptions
    }
}

public class FirefoxWebDriverFactory : IWebDriverFactory<FirefoxOptions>
{
    public IWebDriver GetWebDriver(FirefoxOptions options)
    {
        // implementation details for initalising Firefox and use options from FirefoxOptions
    }
}
```

as @TSmith suggested -> usage:        `var a = new FirefoxWebDriverFactory();`

Comment: That's not possible `IWebDriverFactory<DriverOptions> a = new FirefoxWebDriverFactory();`

Comment: yes, that's why you should use    IWebDriverFactory<FirefoxOptions> a = new FirefoxWebDriverFactory(); for instanciation

Comment: For this I can create an interface `IFirefoxWebDriverFactory` without generics altogether and implement it in concrete class. This does not make any sense. OP wants base interface and many implementations and the way he wants to achieve it is not possible. This should work: `IWebDriverFactory<DriverOptions> a = new FirefoxWebDriverFactory();` but it doesn't.

Comment: it's a difference between Interfect<T> and 3x interfaces, but it's a matter of choice. However, this is a way to fix the question. For sure there are some other ways to do it (from the architectural point of view), but still, this was the question... how it can be done.

Comment: I would slap a constraint on the generic interface declaration: (e.g.,   public interface IWebDriverFactory<in T> where T: DriverOptions ). Also, consider using implicit typing for polymorphic behavior in the test example. (e.g., var a = new FirefoxWebDriverFactory(); )

Comment: That's the interface OP wants `public interface SomeInterface { void Method(BaseType type); }` so that is really `SomeInterface<BaseType>` not `SomeInterface<FirstDerivedClass>`. Your example does compile but is useless in OP use case.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. What other ways (architecturally) are there for this? I'm open to suggestions if there's other ways. Is there something wrong with the current approach taken in this answer? I also don't see why it's useless, it seems to work...

Comment: Oh I see the problem. Now I can't do: `interface Runner() { void Run(IWebDriver driver) }`. I'm getting the impression the solution is to give up and pass the driver options via the constructor of each implementation.

Comment: @user9993 remember the "a" is the factory variable, not the IWebDriver instance. So you'll do: runner.Run(a.GetWebDriver(new FirefoxOptions()));

Comment: Good point, thanks @TSmith. Of the two choices, this way, or via constructor, which do you think is preferable?

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate goal is to be able to get the correct factory for any given configuration.

**Without generics**

```
interface IFactory
{
    bool CanYouMakeIt(IConfig config);
    IMadeThis MakeIt(IConfig config);
}
```

You let all factories implement the interface and then you can all store them in a `List<IFactory>`. Just query all of them with the given config instance and ask them if they can make it. You could also leave out CanYouMakeIt() and let MakeIt just return null if this is not possible for this factory.

```
class SampleFactory : IFactory
{
    public bool CanYouMakeIt(IConfig config) => config.GetType() == typeof(SampleConfig);
    public IMadeThis MakeIt(IConfig config) => new SampleMadeThis(config);
}
```

**Using Generics**

Note: `IFactory` can be omitted, but it makes it handy to store it in a more tightly typed list.

```
interface IFactory {}
interface IFactory<T> :IFactory where T : IConfig
{
    IMadeThis MakeIt(T config);
}

class SampleFactory : IFactory<SampleConfig>
{
    public IMadeThis MakeIt(SampleConfig config) => new SampleMadeThis(config);
}
```

Now invocation is the tricky part. A DI framework like Autofac can make this way easier, but lets see how we would go about this.

I'm not doing any error checking here...

```
class TheUltimateFactory
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type,IFactory> _factories;

    public TheUltimateFactory(IFactory[] factories)
    {
        _factories = factories.ToDictionary(f => GetFactoryType(f.GetType()), f => f);
    }

    private Type GetFactoryType(Type type)
    {
        var genericInterface = type.GetInterfaces().First(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IFactory<>));
        return genericInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

    public IMadeThis MakeIt(IConfig config)
    {
        var configType = config.GetType();
        var method = typeof(IFactory<>).MakeGenericType(configType).GetMethod("MakeIt");
        return (IMadeThis)method.Invoke(_factories[configType], new object[]{config});
    }
}
```

I did not run any of this code, all from the top of my head as I just want to illustrate how you can use reflection for this.

Using the latter approach you basically trade in a strongly typed factory definition against a dynamic invocation code.

Comment: This is a cool approach too; it's really close to the Chain of Responsibility pattern (just need to let the factories fall through to each link vs. requiring the client to go to the next link)

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

> Why is this not possible? I've come into a real world situation where this would be useful.

Useful or not, it is illogical. You are partially violating the contract that the interface stipulates.

To show you why your conclusion is invalid, let's look at the separate steps we took to get there.

```
public class Food {}
public class Meat :  Food {}
public class Poultry : Food {}
public class Tofu :  Food {}
```

Nothing out of the ordinary so far.

Let's say I have a restaurant called Chez Flater. I want to hire chefs, so I draft a contract for what I expect my chefs to do when they're working:

```
public interface IChezFlaterChef
{
    void Cook(Food food);
}
```

Notice what this interface defines. To put the contract into words:

> If you want to be an IChezFlaterChef, you must be able to cook **anything that is Food**.

```
public class VeganChef : IChezFlaterChef
{
    public void Cook(Tofu tofu) {}
}
```

You should now see why this class violates the contract. It wants to be an `IChezFlaterChef`, but it's not actually doing all the jobs that I require of my chefs. The `VeganChef` only wants to cook `Tofu`. I would not hire him.

Your response to this might be "but I only have tofu that needs cooking". This may be correct **today**, but what if I decide that I want to put meat back on the menu tomorrow?

The following code is supposed to always work:

```
IEnumerable<Food> myFood = GetSomeFoods();

foreach(var food in myFoods)
{
    var availableChef = FindAvailableChef();

    chef.Cook(food);
}
```

If you implement your VeganChef the way you want to, this code can blow up at an unexpected time, when he's the available chef and you're asking him to cook something that's not Tofu.

That's a problem. My restaurant is not going to be run efficiently, because I now have to deal with a chef that refuses to work (= throws exception) and I'm going to have to look for a second chef.
I specifically required all of my chefs to be able to cook any food **because I did not want this to happen**. Either I should not expect this of my cooks; or I should not have hired the vegan chef. The compiler is pointing out that I should not be hiring the chef:

> 'Implementation' does not implement interface member 'SomeInterface.Method(BaseType)'

Is equivalent to

> [The VeganChef] does not do the expected [cooking of any food].

In other words, the compiler is preventing you from opening your restaurant because it knows that this VeganChef is going to be a problem for you once the restaurant is up and running.

When you're writing code, you have no way of knowing which exact chefs and foods will be used in this particular restaurant, because the staff and menu hasn't been decided yet (we're still developing the restaurant itself)

If I write this code:

```
public string GetEmployeeName(Employee e)
{
    return e.Name;
}
```

This relies on the logic that **every** Employee is **guaranteed** to have a Name property.

But your `VeganChef` cannot cook **every** food. Since I require my `IChezFlaterChef`s to be able to cook any food, that logically means that `VeganChef` cannot be hired as an `IChezFlaterChef`.

---

### Solution

Your current IChezFlaterChef contract is simply not correct:

> If you want to be an IChezFlaterChef, you must be able to cook **anything that is Food**.

What you want is more correctly expressed as:

> If you want to be an IChezFlaterChef **for a particular food type**, you must be able to cook **that particular food type**.

As the restaurant owner, I've changed my expectations of what it means to be a chef in my restaurant. Instead of requiring all my chefs to be able to cook all my food, I'm now open to hiring specialists who can only cook one particular food.

When a chef wants to be an `IChezFlaterChef`, the obvious first question then becomes "for what food?". That information is provided by a **generic type**:

```
public interface IChezFlaterChef<TFood> where T : Food
{
    void Cook(TFood food);
}
```

Notice `where T : Food`. This ensure that you can't do things like creating an `IChezFlaterChef<DateTime>` which makes no sense.

```
public class VeganChef : IChezFlaterChef<Tofu>
{
    public void Cook(Tofu tofu) {}
}
```

And now this class is valid, because it fulfills the contract that `IChezFlaterChef<TFood>` has defined.

Suppose you want a chef that can cook two foods. You can do this, but you must implement the interface twice (each with a different food type):

```
public class MeatAndPoultryChef : IChezFlaterChef<Meat>, IChezFlaterChef<Poultry>
{
    //Needed for IChezFlaterChef<Meat>
    public void Cook(Meat meat) {}

    //Needed for IChezFlaterChef<Poultry>
    public void Cook(Poultry poultry) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading question

> Why can't derived classes be substituted in place of base classes in interface members?

I'm explaining why you cannot do that, instead of showing how you can do that in other ways.

As per your contract interface `interface SomeInterface` 
Every class which implements this interface must have a method `Method(BaseType type)` which can accept every those classes' object which implements `BaseType`.

meaning, object of all those classes which implements `BaseType` can be passed in `Method()`.

but in your derived class `class Implementation : SomeInterface` , when have tried to override that method, this can accept only `FirstDerivedClass` type's object.

meaning,

if someone creates another class say `Demo` which implements `BaseType`, now as per interface's method, this class's object too can be passed in `Method(BaseType type)` but as your derived class `Implementation` does have method which only accept `FirstDerivedClass` only, it will not accept `Demo`'s object.

one such class (same as `Demo`) is already there in your code only, `SecondDerivedClass`

So it violates the contract.

In your derived class `Implementation` too, method should be such which can accept every those classes' object which implements `BaseType`.

Way to do it, simply accept `BaseType` Typed instance in method of `Implementation`.

`public void Method(Base type) {}` instead of `public void Method(FirstDerivedClass type) {}`

Here in first line of this method you can cast type from `Base` to `FirstDerivedClass` by `FirstDerivedClass obj = (FirstDerivedClass)type`.

*This line isn't required to be dynamic, as you know which type should be here at coding time*