# Force input based on interface

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have an abstract class, which forces the implementation of a method, which takes an interface as input, like this:

```
public abstract DocumentWriter
{
    (...)
    protected abstract void FillContent(IDocumentArgs args);
}
```

The interface `IDocumentArgs` is created to ensure that certain properties is included in the arguments, which is otherwise largely dependent on the implementation of `DocumentWriter`.

```
public interface IDocumentArgs
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Subject { get; set; }
    string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Based on this interface, I have made an implementation of this interface, which is to be used in the implementation of the `DocumentWriter`. It looks something like this:

```
public class ActualDocumentArgs : IDocumentArgs
{
    // Properties enforced by the interface
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Subject { get; set; }
    string Author { get; set; }

    // Custom properties
    string CustomerName { get; set; }
    DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

The **problem** is: I want to implement `FillContent()` using the `ActualDocumentArgs` (which I suppose should be possible, since it implements `IDocumentArgs`), like this:

```
public class ActualDocumentWriter : DocumentWriter
{
    (...)    
    protected override void FillContent(ActualDocumentArgs args)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

But if I do this, I get a compile time error:

> 'ActualDocumentWriter.FillContent(ActualDocumentArgs)': no suitable method found to override.

On the other hand, I cannot use `IDocumentArgs` as input, since I won't have access to the custom properties then.

How to get around this issue? It is giving me a headache...

Comment: can you `DocumentWriter<T> where T : IDocumentArgs` and then `protected abstract void FillContent(T args);` and `class ActualDocumentWriter : DocumentWriter<ActualDocumentArgs>` ?

Comment: You can not strengthen the contract when implementing the abstract class. It requires you to accept _any_ `IDocumentArgs`, not only `ActualDocumentArgs`.

The question is why do you need the `DocumentWriter` class to begin with?

Comment: @DennisKuypers the `DocumentWriter` contains some non-abstract methods, which can then be used by the actual implementation(s). I wan't to define that any implementation of the `DocumentWriter` should implement a `FillContent` method, which takes an input based on (but not limited to) `IDocumentsArgs`. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Noceo Good choice on going with an abstract class to provide utility methods to decendants. The FillDocument is `protected` in your case. Who is calling this then? (maybe this doesn't have to be part of the abstract class contract then. If you will have multiple document information types and you have to find out who the responsible document writer is you could go with something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371510/why-cant-derived-classes-be-substituted-in-place-of-base-classes-in-interface-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current abstract class requires that the method accept anything implementing `IDocumentArgs`.  You *could* perhaps check the type when it's passed in, but the compiler itself wouldn't be enforcing it.

One thing you could do is change your abstract class to be generic.  Something like this:

```
public abstract class DocumentWriter<T> where T : IDocumentArgs
{
    protected abstract void FillContent(T args);
}
```

Note the `where` constraint on the type parameter, requiring that implementing types use only a derivative of `IDocumentArgs` as the type parameter.

Then when you implement that class, provide the type parameter explicitly:

```
public class ActualDocumentWriter : DocumentWriter<ActualDocumentArgs>
{ 
    protected override void FillContent(ActualDocumentArgs args)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but means that my interface `IDocumentWriter` is no longer being used. This is no big deal though, as it had little practical effect.

Comment: @Noceo: Well, since your original code wasn't using an `IDocumentWriter` interface either, I don't see the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```
public abstract DocumentWriter<T>
  where T : IDocumentArgs
{
    (...)
    protected abstract void FillContent(T args);
}

public class ActualDocumentWriter : DocumentWriter<ActualDocumentArgs>
{
    (...)    
    protected override void FillContent(ActualDocumentArgs args)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I cannot use IDocumentArgs as input, since I won't have access to the custom properties then.

Is an indication of a design error. 
You should not be wanting that.

You can circumvent it, inside the override method you can typecast it:

```
protected override void FillContent(IDocumentArgs args)
{
    var actualArgs = args as ActualDocumentArgs ;
    // Do stuff
}
```

but this is a hack.

Comment: We don't always get to pick the ideal design and interfaces.